# Which is better for solar inverters - High volts low amps solar arrays vs low volts high amps solar arrays?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, solar-cell

I want to know how the two ways of making the solar arrays affect the AC power load that the inverter can supply.

Comment: I would say it is a balance. Low voltage and high current means you need to spend more on copper/cables. Going for a higher voltage saves money on copper up until you reach issues with cable insulation and/or max input voltage to the inverter. The "problem" is not so much on the inverter side as it is on the supply side. (Generally speaking, each inverter may have their own issues)

Answer (score 1):

A high voltage array can use smaller cross-section cables to connect it to the inverter, or can be sited further from the inverter, than a low voltage array.

For 'reasonable' voltages, in the several 10s to several 100s range, there's not a lot of difference between the efficiency of commercial inverters.

Answer (score 0):

Comparably higher voltage is more preferable when given choice between different voltages.
One advantage is the lower cross-section of copper wire and assuming you are a DIYer you would want to save on that, the otherwise second advantage is that low power is lost on the lines at high voltages and currents and it matters a lot in high power systems.

The third and most distinctive advantage is the higher efficiency of inverters at higher input voltages. If you see the datasheet of the inverters with two input voltage options they are more efficient in converting higher input voltage to mains voltage than converting lower input voltage to the same mains voltage.

Final advantage relates to the third one that inverter can handle more power while converting a higher input voltage to mains voltage than a lower voltage to the same mains voltage you could check that too in the datasheet of the inverters.

Higher voltage does not mean that you could go as high as you want or you could hook as many panels as you have in series. You should look at the max input voltage rating of the inverter you are going to use and the max series voltage of the panels. If using the system at home(rooftop) I would suggest not exceed 100v DC until power gets limited due to voltage.
The problem here is that you have not mentioned the scale of the system under consideration. My answer is most relatable to low to moderate power domestic systems.

Comment: by "domestic" what country are you referring to?

Comment: These days domestic solar installments range from a few hundred watts to a few kilowatts given that there is no intention to commercialize the system (sell the electricity generated from it). The size has nothing to do with country I suppose.